# POST a List<T> to MVC Controller always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework, jquery

I'm trying to Post a List to my MVC Controller..

**The Controller:**    `// POST api/UserFollows`

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostUserFollows(List<FollowItem> followItemList)
{
   //I'M GETTING NULL IN followItemList
   if(followItemList==null)
   {
      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
   }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
STATUS 400 Bad Request <-- Means I got null in followItemList
TIME 4025 ms
Cache-Control →no-cache
Connection →Close
Content-Length →0
Date →Tue, 29 Jan 2013 09:38:31 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
Server →ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version →4.0.30319
```

**The `FollowItem` class**

```
namespace Helpers.SubClasses
{
    public class FollowItem
    {
        public bool action;
        public long FollowsUserId;
    }
}
```

I tried a lot of request but none of them works.. I always get null!

**THE POST METHOD:**

```
function postFollowList() {
            $.ajax( {
            url: Request_Url + "api/UserFollows",
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                    {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456777},
                    {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456888}
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function( data )
            {
                $('#newmovie').html("OK");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) 
            {
                $('#newmovie').html('Error: ' + err);
            }
             });
```

**The requests:** //As JSON - I'm Using [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm)

```
1.
    [
        {"action":"true","FollowsUserId":"123456777"}
    ]
2.
    [
        {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456777},
        {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456888}
    ]
3.
    {[
        {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456777},
        {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456888}
    ]}
4.
    {followItemList:[
        {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456777},
        {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456888}
    ]}
```

**Example for null:**

[image: Example]

**I tried a lot more..
Can anybody please help me with this?
Thanks!!!**

**EDIT:**
The answer was that I sent `application/xml` in the content-type when I needed to send `application/json`.

Comment: When do you get null? What is your code doing and what does "I get null" mean here?

Comment: How do you post? Please show full code.

Comment: @RoyDictus Added more info

Comment: @ken2k Added the Post Method
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON doesn't appear to be valid.  Perhaps try this:

```
[
    {
        "action": true,
        "FollowsUserId": 123456777
    },
    {
        "action": true,
        "FollowsUserId": 123456888
    }
]
```

A good tool to check JSON validity is [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: I'm still Getting a null List.. I added an Image in the question. Thanks!

Comment: For a POST you should be sending in "Content-Type" with value "application/json".

Comment: My Bad.. The List was on a different type than FollowItem.
And the "Content-Type" was with a value "application/xml"
Thanks for the help and thank for the JSON validity

Answer (score 1):

I tried this -

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var foo = new List<FollowItem>()
        {
            new FollowItem {action = true, FollowsUserId = 123456777},
            new FollowItem {action = true, FollowsUserId = 123456888}
        };
        return new JsonResult {Data = foo, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
    }

    //
    // POST: /Home/
    public ActionResult Dump(List<FollowItem> followItems)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(followItems);
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }

}
public class FollowItem
{
    public bool action;
    public long FollowsUserId;
}
```

And post this -

```
[
  {"action":true,"FollowsUserId":123456777},
  {"action":true,"FollowsUserId":123456888}
]
```

And this works. Please note that this is how it sends the response as well.

Comment: Hmm... I'm trying to POST to my controller
It's seems that you are showing how to Post JSON string on request

Comment: The Dump action takes a POST, The Index action just gives you the serialized JSON, that you can post back.

Comment: I tried to POST to it.. and I always get into the `public ActionResult Index()`

Comment: You should post to ~/Home/Dump. The default action is Index

Comment: Thanks.. My problem was the Content-Type. but thanks for the new info!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the variable name to data. See the following code.

```
function postFollowList() {
        $.ajax( {
        url: Request_Url + "api/UserFollows",
        type: 'post',
        data: { followItemList: [
            {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456777},
            {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456888}
        ]},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( data )
        {
            $('#newmovie').html("OK");
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) 
        {
            $('#newmovie').html('Error: ' + err);
        }
});
```

Edit: Maybe you can try to serialize the array before posting it:

```
        data: { followItemList: JSON.stringify([
            {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456777},
            {action: true, FollowsUserId: 123456888}
        ])},
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help, Now I get in the controller `followItemList.Count = 0`
What do you think it is?

Comment: Still Count=0
Maybe the call don't recognized the action,FollowsUserId vars?

Comment: Thanks! The problem was in the content-type . Thanks!